# Calendar Changing Dates

Tags: java, calendar

Calendar is changing the date loaded from a database

```
    // resultset fetching database content

    results = tp.getProjectTasks(projID);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    int month, day, year, endMonth, endDay, endYear;

    while (results.next()) {

        month = Integer.parseInt(smf.format(smf.parse(results.getString(7))));
        year = Integer.parseInt(syf.format(syf.parse(results.getString(7))));
        day = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(sdf.parse(results.getString(7))));

        cal.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        Date startWork = cal.getTime();            

        // date is fine here

        System.out.println("CAL:"+results.getString(8));

        endMonth = Integer.parseInt(smf.format(smf.parse(results.getString(8))));
        endYear = Integer.parseInt(syf.format(syf.parse(results.getString(8))));
        endDay = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(sdf.parse(results.getString(8))));

        // dates have changed here

        System.out.println(endYear+":"+endMonth+":"+endDay);

        cal.set(endYear, endMonth, endDay, 0, 0, 0);
        //cal.set(2019, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0);
        Date endWork = cal.getTime();

        // endWork has incorrect Dates

        taskModel.add(new TimelineEvent(new Task(results.getString(2), "images/timeline/mail.png", true), startWork, endWork));

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question is a bit too vague at the moment - we don't know what exactly has changed (`cal`? `startWork`? Both?) or in what way. What are `smf`, `syf` etc? Why are you asking them to parse and format in the same statement? If you could provide a [mcve] that would make it *much* easier to help you. I'd also advise using `java.time` instead of `Calendar` and `Date` if you *possibly* can.

Comment: “is fine” and “have changed” are vague. Please give a precise example of expected and observed result. Also as @JonSkeet I recommend that you don’t use `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`, those classes are long outdated and poorly designed. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed all the statements to getDate() instead of getString() and the problem went away. It seems the app did not like parsing the date which was pulled from the database so I just retrieved it from the database as a Date and not String, removing the need to parse the retrieved data.

Comment: Thanks for reporting your solution. Nowadays (since JDBC 4.2) you should use `results.getObject(7, LocalDate.class)` to retrieve a `LocalDate`. It’s one of the classes in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (`getDate` is an improvement over `getString` too).

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it